# Is it an anti-pattern to send a request object to a model method in Django?

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I am currently trying to use the `fat model, thin view` pattern, moving almost all the logic to model methods.

While doing it, I am constantly finding myself sending a `request` object from a view to a model method:

```
model_method(request)
```

and using it in the following way:

```
def model_method(self, request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    user_type = request.user.__class__.__name__

    ...
```

Is this a good idea? or should I send what I want from the request object to the method, instead of the whole object, like this:

```
user_id = request.user.id
user_type = request.user.__class__.__name__

model_method(user_id, user_type)
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: It sounds like it destroys the MVC that django has done so well to create but that is just my opinion. Your question is opinion based and off-topic.

Comment: This kind of question always depends about your project´s requeriments, Business´s Model, and so on... But, We use to avoid the fact of sending innecesary information between layers... For so many things: Security, performance, maintainability,...

Comment: Once you start passing the request just to access one or two attributes, you're treating it a bit like a [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). You're introducing unnecessary tight coupling between the request object and your method, when you only need a `User` instance. Later on you might need to call this method with a user object, when you don't actually have a request object. In other cases you may need the request (e.g. to access the session or set a cookie), so passing the request is the only solution that makes sense.

Comment: @knbk thank you! if you could post it as an answer, I would accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@knbk's answer that he posted as a comment:

Once you start passing the request just to access one or two attributes, you're treating it a bit like a God object. You're introducing unnecessary tight coupling between the request object and your method, when you only need a User instance. Later on you might need to call this method with a user object, when you don't actually have a request object. In other cases you may need the request (e.g. to access the session or set a cookie), so passing the request is the only solution that makes sense